# Azure web app with sqlite database

Tags: sqlite-net, azure-web-app-service

i'd like to create a simple azure web app, which stores data within the folder where it is deployed (`..\wwwroot\`).
I downloaded the provided sample code from "myapp".azurewebsites.net but there EntityFramework is used. Is it possible to configure EF to use SQLite or do I need to implement my own SQLite Provider? (...using the PCL version from https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/
Can someone recommend me any samples? I didn't find suitable snippets for SQLite on Azure.

This is my code so far:

```
public class DataService
{
    private static string sqliteFilename = "myDbName.sqlite";
    private static SQLiteConnection dbConnection;

    public static bool Initialize()
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\App_Data\"));
        string path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\App_Data\"), sqliteFilename);
        dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(path);
        dbConnection.CreateTable<Category>();
        dbConnection.CreateTable<User>();
        return true;
    }
}
```

I get an error, that doesn't tell me much about it...

> The type initializer for 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files of a deployment package are uploaded into the Azure Runtime environment, and persisted in the directory d:\home. These files are persistent and are shared between multiple instances of the site. In the Free and Shared tiers of the Web App the persistent storage limit is 1 GB, while Basic and Standard tiers get 10GB and 50GB.

So instead of creating the sqlite file in code; pre-create it, and upload it with as a file among the set of deployed files. Use kudu to find the actual path to the file and reference that in your code.

Ref: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment#file-system

The drawback of this approach is that the database file would be replaced every time a deployment is performed.